# For every $a\in [0,1]$ there is a subsequence converging to $a$.

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence in $[0,1]$ given by $ \left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{8},\frac{7}{8},\frac{1}{16},\frac{3}{16},\frac{5}{16},\ldots \right)$

Prove that for any $a\in [0,1]$ there is a subsequence converging to $a$.

Now when I draw the sequence on line it makes good sense to me why this is true. However i don't know how to prove it. Any help out there?

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Note that any $a \in [0,1]$ can be written as
$$a = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a_k}{2^k}$$ where $a_k \in \{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** It suffices to show that every rational number is a limit of a subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

Different hint: Show that the set of values in the sequence is dense in $[0,1]$.