# Find a sequence (Sn) that for any a between [0,1] there is a subsequence of Sn that converges to a.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences, farey-sequences

Find a sequence (Sn) that for any a between [0,1] there is a subsequence of Sn that converges to a.

I've been stumped for days, my guess is that it is an addition of sequences each expressing its own decimal place, but I can't figure out how to make that consider all possibilities.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576639/for-every-a-in-0-1-there-is-a-subsequence-converging-to-a

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$\mathbb Q$ is a countable set, meaning that there exists a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$. Also, $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, \ldots, 0.9, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, \ldots 0.09, 0.11, 0.12, \ldots, 0.19, \ldots 0.99, 0.001, 0.002, \ldots$

It's somewhat simpler in binary:

$0, 0.1, 0.01, 0.11, 0.001, 0.011, 0.101, 0.111, \ldots$

Answer (score 0):

One possible sequence :

$$S = (0,0,\frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4}, \frac{3}{4} , \cdots ) $$

We can write this as

$$S_{2^n+k} = \frac{k}{2^n}$$

for $0 \leq k< 2^n$